# First use of array is slow

Tags: php, sql, arrays, typo3, extbase

I have encountered a weird "bug" in PHP and since I'm a novice I'm at the end of my knowledge.

I'm developing a TYPO3 extension that has some major performance issues with data, or so I thought. 
It turns out that the first use of the array, which stores all the objects I got from my database query, is taking way to long. 
Every use or loop after that is fast again.

The code looks like this:

```
        $productsArr = $this->productRepository->findByDetail($category, $properties);

        $newSortArr = array();
        $familyProductList = array();

        $counter = count($productsArr);
        /** @var Product $product */
        for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {

            //it takes to long to do this
            $product = $productsArr[$i];

            if(!empty($productsArr[$i])) {
                $newSortArr[$product->getInFamily()->getUid()][] = $product;
            }
        }
```

It doesn't matter where I first use the object array. The first use of the array is always taking around 30 sec.

Has anybody encountered something similar? 
If you need more information I will gladly provide that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably the query is "heavy", and after the first use is still in your db server's query cache, so you get quicker responses next time around.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TYPO3, but translated to Symfony/Doctrine terms it seems you may fetch a list of products from the database, then accessing some relation inside the loop (`getInFamily`). This _may_ mean you are lazy loading this data - meaning you're firing off another database query for each product in the loop. Count the queries that runs, or skip the `$newSortArr` line and see if the loop runs faster without doing that. Either would suggest that might be the case. Usually resolved by joining in the associated relation so it's added to the result set and not fetched using lazy loading.

Comment: @MarcB but the query executes quite fast. Only the first use of the array, like when I assign it to another variable takes to long

Comment: @JimL the getInFamily request isn't breaking it. The part above the if ( $product = $productsArr[$i]; ) takes ages. Before that line the first use of the $productsArr was in the if, and that took to long too.

Answer (score 4):

Your `$productsArr` is not an array but an Object of Exbase's class `QueryResult` which you can iterate over with foreach or do index access. This Object execute the query and build it's objects only when needed, so at the moment you do `$product = $productsArr[$i];`, all `Product`-objects of `$productsArr`are built. The major problem is that building objects in PHP has bad performance and consumpts a lot of memory.

So, to avoid the performance issue, consider using a custom query with

```
$this->productRepository->createQuery()->statement('select * from ...')->execute();
```

to get exactly what you want instead of loading a huge amount of objects and refine them later in PHP.

Comment: This is a correct answer, however your solution is not recommended. You should really avoid using custom statement, since they are inherently less safe, bigger chance of compatiblity issues with a different SQL database and in most cases you could build them nicely with extbase query functions: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

Comment: @JozefSpisiak I agree! As long as it is possible to build a query with default extbase query functions I'd highly recommend everyone to use them instead of using a custom query.

But sadly, it's not possible to join tables with extbase query functions. This is why I use custom queries in that case.

Answer (score 2):

As Jay already mentioned, your result isn't an array, but a `QueryResult`. Just FYI, it's possible to transform it to an array by adding `->toArray()` at the end of your query:

```
$productsArr = $this->productRepository->findByDetail($category, $properties)->toArray();
```

But this won't improve the situation. There are two possible issues:

**Iterating all objects**

The advantage of a `QueryResult` is that it reflects only the result of the query but doesn't resolve all objects already. A QueryResult can be passed e.g. to a Pagination widget and will then only load the results requested (e.h. 1-10, 11-20 etc.).

Since you're applying manual sorting, all your objects (depending on your project this can be a lot...) are loaded.

Apparently you would like to sort the products by their family UID? Why not do that with Extbase functionality in your `ProductRepository`:

```
protected $defaultOrderings = array(
    'inFamily.uid' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
);
```

**Eager loading of sub objects**

Your model `Product` might have relations to other models (e.h. Product to Category, Product to Options etc.). By default, Extbase resolves all these relations on accessing the objects.

To prevent this, you can use Lazy Loading for relations. This makes sense for sub objects that are not used in all the views. E.g. in your list view you only need to title, image and price of your product, but you don't need all options of the product.

To configure lazy loading for these sub objects, you just need to `@lazy` annotation in the model:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\My\Extension\Domain\Model\ObjectStorageModel>
 * @lazy
 */
protected $categories;

/**
 * @var \My\Extension\Domain\Model\OtherModel
 * @lazy
 */
protected $author;
```

Lazy loading can have some drawbacks, e.g. in certain situations when checking for an object being an instance of `OtherModel`, you get an object of type `LazyLoadingProxy` instead. You can work around most of these issues or maybe don't even stumple upon them in normal scenarios. A common workaround if you really depend an object on not being a LazyLoadingProxy is a check like that:

```
if ($product->getAuthor() instanceof \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyLoadingProxy) {
    $product->getAuthor()->_loadRealInstance();
}
```

This makes sure that in any case you have a "real" instance of the object.

Please don't forget to flush system caches when you're doing a change regarding either one of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the array is populated on the first line. Have you considered populating `$product` using `foreach($productArr as $product)` instead o using `for`?

Comment: Yes, that's something I did before, but for the first loop it still had the same issues.

Comment: What is productArr supposed to contain? Are there - for example - base64 encoded images or other large columns? If yes, then maybe you should test by eliminating those from the result just to rule this out from the list o suspects.

Comment: $productArr contains product objects. The product objects  also have child objects associated with them.